# Simplicial homology: $n$-fold dunce cap as a complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was trying to solve Exercise 6.6 of [Chapter 1, Elements of algebraic topology, Munkres, 1984] (so I think this exercise does not need results after Section 6 of Chapter 1). I found it is a little hard to understand the $5$-fold dunce cap so I tried $3$-fold dunce cap first, which seems simple:

> Let $v$ be the "$3$ vertices" of the $3$-fold dunce cap and I get $B_1=\langle 3[v,v]\rangle$, since there is only one 2-simplex $[v,v,v]$. $Z_1=\langle[v,v]\rangle$ so $H_1\cong\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z.$

[image: Image of 3-fold dunce hat (as Munkres, the triangle should also be colored)]

Is this proof reasonable or not? I want to do the same for $n\geq4$, but what are the **2-simplexes** of $n$-dunce hat? I thought $[v,v,v]$ is the only one but it came with $B_1=\langle[v,v]\rangle$, which seems unacceptable.

Apologize if anything is not clear or wrong.

Comment: If you want to use simplicial homology to do this, then you need to subdivide your space so it is a genune simplicial complex. As is, writing down $[v,v,v]$ does not specify the simplex. It could be the triangle pictured, or it could be a constant map where the entire simplex gets mapped to a point. In order to perform simplicial homology calculations, you need a subdivision where every simplex is uniquely specified by its vertices.

Comment: I think the model should be to imitate Lemma 6.1. (This problem is in Section 6 of my copy of Munkres, not section 5.) If you triangulate the polygon to get a valid simplicial complex, then every 1-cycle should be homologous to a 1-cycle "carried by" the boundary of the polygon, and something along the same lines for 2-chains. Your computations will fill in some parts of a full proof.

Comment: Thanks for comments.